# Change status message in WahtsApp, Skype and Hangout?

Tags: android, skype, whatsapp, google-hangouts

I have many research on WahtsApp, Skype and Hangout for changing it's status message using codding in android.

- WhatsApp : No any SDK or API.  But we can share single message using
  codding.
- Skype : Only open skype app.  [Fore more preferences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn745884.aspx)
- Hangout :  Get status but not get or update status message.  [Fore more preferences](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout.data#gapi.hangout.data.getStateMetadata)

If anybody have idea about how to changes status message of WahtsApp, Skype and Hangout, Please share detail.

Comment: let me try on this if i found sure tell you